# How to specify timezones for World Clock in Bosun?

Tags: bosun

How should I specify timezones for Word Clock in Bosun config?

I think there was some parameter for that but I can't find reference in docs for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration parameter for the worldclock links is `timeAndDate`. Note this ONLY controls the links generated when displaying datetimes and doesn't control Bosun's timezone, which is hardcoded to UTC.

In the code:

`TimeAndDate      []int // timeanddate.com cities list`

So our config file looks like:

`timeAndDate = 202,75,179,136`

Which adds Portland, Denver, New York, and London to the datetime links generated in alerts:

[image: timeanddate.com]

See http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converter-about.html for how to get a list of Cities, and then you will find the p_=### codes in the URL that you can add to your Bosun config.

I've created [an issue](https://github.com/bosun-monitor/bosun/issues/1531) in the github issue tracker to get this fixed.